# Can someone be an administrator of a festival?

Tags: word-choice

Someone is in charge of organizing a festival/meeting/conference etc.
What do we call him? Can we say he is the administrator of that festival? What word suits better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally use "organizer" or "coordinator". I would tend to use "organizer" for larger events and "coordinator" for smaller events, but I wouldn't say it's a hard and fast rule.

**Examples**

> festival organizer
>   meeting organizer
>   conference organizer
>   event organizer
>
> meeting coordinator
>   event coordinator

Comment: thx. In one of them I had to manage 30 people as staff and the number of audience was 400. is it big enough to call the person who did this an organizer?

Comment: @Juya Yes, I would call that person an organizer.

Comment: At our local university there is a course/discipline called "Events Management" - perhaps Event Manager would suit?

Comment: @toandfro I can definitely see calling someone an "event manager".

Answer (score 4):

"Administrator" as a title is usually reserved for either:

1. Heads of entities, especially those titled "administration". For example, the head of the BPA http://www.bpa.gov/news/AboutUs/Execs/Pages/Bill-Drummond.aspx. Note that the head of the US EPA (an Agency) is titled "Administrator of the EPA".
2. Positions involving overseeing and actively managing information technology objects, like computers, networks and files. In this case they are usually called "system administrators", "network administrators", "license administrators", and so on.

It is not incorrect to use the word administrator - the meaning is easily understood by readers - but godel9's suggestions are more common in English and sound more fluent, if that is important to you.